# Formatting numbers in R when using group_by in dplyr

Tags: r, dplyr

I currently have the following R code, which is grouping the data into "bands", based upon the value in the column BLANLIMAMT.  This works perfectly.

```
library(dplyr)


#Import the data
MyData <- read.csv("LibFile.csv", stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

#Profile the Data
bTable<- MyData %>% 
  group_by(gr=cut(BLANLIMAMT, breaks= seq(0, 50000000, by = 500000)) )%>% 
  summarise(n= n()) %>%
  arrange(as.numeric(gr))
```

My issues is with formatting the output.  The values in column gr (in bTable) currently look like (0,5e+05).  I would like them to look like 0 to 500,000 etc.  Here is a screenshot of the table:

[Here is a screenshot of the table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/axAyq.png)

Any thoughts on how I would achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

use `dig.lab=8` within cut. for example

```
bTable<- MyData %>% 
  group_by(gr=cut(BLANLIMAMT, breaks= seq(0, 50000000, by = 500000), dig.lab=8) )%>% 
  summarise(n= n()) %>%
  arrange(as.numeric(gr))
```

It gives the number of digits before it switches to scientific notation.

Comment: This is great, thank you.  Is there a way to add the "'," so 500000 becomes 500,000?

Comment: Uhhh, I guess this is something you have to do manually by overwriting the levels...

Answer (score 0):

Use `options("scipen"=100, "digits"=4)`

You can play with exact numbers to your liking :).

‘scipen’: integer. A penalty to be applied when deciding to print numeric values in fixed or exponential notation. Positive values bias towards fixed and negative towards scientific notation: fixed notation will be preferred unless it is more than ‘scipen’ digits wider.

Source: https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/options.html